# IE stops scrolling for some web pages

Tags: internet-explorer, nokia-lumia-1020

Out of interest, any of you had issues where your IE on windows phone 8 or 8.1 stops scrolling? It's been an issue since I got the phone (Nokia lumia 1020), and seems to happen mostly on Yahoo.

If I put it into reader mode it works, but still a bit annoying

Comment: Can you share a link to a site which gives you trouble?

Comment: I've had the same problem. I'll post back here if I run across one again. Sometimes you can get around it by going into reading mode.